# How do I get my converted object using @JmsListener

Tags: spring, jaxb, jms

I am using Spring and Jaxb to listen to a JMSQueue and then unmarshall the JMS message into a java object. I am then expecting to get that Java Object on my `@JmsListener` endpoint. But instead I'm getting a `TextMessage` object.  Using a debugger I can step through the code and see that the conversion to the java object is happening but it never makes it to my end point.

Here is my config:

```java
@Bean
  public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myContainerFactory() {
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
              new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
      factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryProxy());
      factory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
      factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
      factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
      return factory;
  }
  
  @Bean
  public MessageConverter messageConverter(){
    MarshallingMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingMessageConverter();
    Jaxb2Marhsaller jaxbMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marhsaller ();
    jaxbMarshaller.setPackagesToScan("mypackage.jms.model");
    converter.setUnmarshaller(jaxbMarshaller);
    converter.setMarshaller(jaxbMarshaller);
    return converter;
  }
```

And my endpoint:

```java
@Component
public class QueueMessageReceiver {

  @JmsListener(containerFactory = "myContainerFactory", destination = "jms/Queue")
  public void process(Message message) {
    try {
      System.out.println(message);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

The problem is that the `QueueMessageReceiver.process` method has a `TextMessage` and not the converted object.

Comment: Change your process method instead of the `Message` use the type of object you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the process method to use the object you are expecting and not Message

```
 @JmsListener(containerFactory = "myContainerFactory", destination = "jms/Queue")
  public void process(YourAwesomeObject theObject) {
           ....
  }
```